# JXDatePicker swingx language

Tags: java, datepicker, date-format, arabic, swingx

**Modified question** How to make JXDatePicker use a specified language ?

Comment: Link to the project supplying this date picker, or at least say it’s fully-qualified name (its package).

Comment: Lemme guess, https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html?

Comment: A tip: When posting on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere too) , follow the Java naming conventions. A variable name starts with a small letter. It makes it easier for your reader. It’s particularly confusing that you’ve got a variable of type `String` that has the same name as the class `Date`. I suggest `datePicker` instead of `DateDP` and `dateString` instead of `Date`.

Comment: Sorry for this, and thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `JXDatePicker` is dependent on the old Java date and time classes including `Date` and `DateFormat`. It’s unfortunate because they are poorly designed and have later (5 years ago) been replaced with java.time, the modern Java date and time API. You may want to research whether you can find a more modern date picker component to replace it.

Failing that, `JXDatePicker.setFormats` does require either `DateFormat` objects or `String` objects. The reasonable solution is to pass a `Locale` to your `SimpleDateFormat` before passing it to the date picker:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

For formatting the `Date` that you get from the date picker you have the option of converting it to a modern type before formatting it:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("E, yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date oldfashionedDate = DateDP.getDate();
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = oldfashionedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String dateString = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateString);
```

Specifying English locale for the `DateTimeFormatter` makes sure that the formatted date will have the abbreviation for day of week in English, for example:

> Mon, 2019-08-05

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [`JXDatePicker` documentation](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html)